# bs-modal not showing content in AngularStrap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-strap

That's basically my question, here a Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/SNFy2XcOBefUavG1QCqD?p=preview

```
   <button class="btn btn-default"
           data-template="customer.tpl.html"
           bs-modal="modal">New Customer
   </button>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" ng-show="title">
        <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="$hide()">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" ng-bind="title">Hello</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" ng-bind="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$hide()">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* showing the template, but it does not seems that way because you have `ng-bind="content"` in the template. This means that the modal will replace any `modal-body` content with the content of the `data-content` attribute (or if passed by javascript). Your `data-content` is nothing, so the "*Lorem ipsum ...*" is replaced with `""`.

So change

```
<div class="modal-body" ng-bind="content">
```

to

```
<div class="modal-body">
```

and it works.

forked plnkr -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/18cyHRx8fQ6gXrdLnWG8?p=preview**